# Dataframe split but get error 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Some String problems reflect on Dataframe in Python

While i try to split the 2nd '_' of a string, python returns error!

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series    

wkRep = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')
df = DataFrame(wkRep,columns=['Src','Campaign','Region','Profit','Purchased'])
df['Region']=df.Campaign.apply(lambda x: x.split('_').str[1])
df
```

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`

Campaign's samples looks like this:

**AAA_BBB_New Zeon_Dec 25 2017**

i wanna only put **New Zeon** into Region be a new column in Dataframe.

Comment: 1. Don't use apply. 2. it's just `x.split('_')[1]`.

Comment: Instead, just use `df.Campaign.str.split('_').str[1]`

Comment: `df['Region']=df.Campaign(lambda x: x.split('_')[2])` that returns TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable.
The other way is successful and i make a mistake. it should be[2] rather than [1]. [2] is **New Zeon** that i want. THANK YOU.